# Covert each key and value in to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How covert or add each key and value into separate array.

**Now**

```
var arr = {
  "3/10/2017": 52,
  "3/11/2017": 58,
  "3/12/2017": 70,
  "3/13/2017": 76
}
```

**Result should be**

```
var arr = [
  ["3/10/2017", 52],
  ["3/11/2017", 58],
  ["3/12/2017", 70],
  ["3/13/2017", 76]
]
```

Thank you

Comment: array not with keys and values .its only have a arguments

Comment: `["3/10/2017": 52]` isn't valid JavaScript. Did you mean `{"3/10/2017": 52}` instead?

Comment: If you wanted `[["3/10/2017", 52],...` - then it's as easy as `Object.entries(arr)` - however, what you *want* is invalid

Comment: Please respecify what you want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` method in combination with `Object.keys()`.`map`  method accepts a `callback` function which is applied to every item in the array.

```js
var arr = {
  "3/10/2017": 52,
  "3/11/2017": 58,
  "3/12/2017": 70,
  "3/13/2017": 76
};
console.log(Object.keys(arr).map(function(item){
    return [item,arr[item]];
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

`["3/13/2017": 76]` is actually invalid array, but you could replace `:` with e.g. comma `,` or just push it to every array as an object.

```js
var arr = {
  "3/10/2017": 52,
  "3/11/2017": 58,
  "3/12/2017": 70,
  "3/13/2017": 76
},
res = Object.keys(arr).map(v => new Array(v, arr[v])),
res2 = Object.keys(arr).map(v => new Array({[v]: arr[v]}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, 2, null));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res2, 2, null));
```

Comment: This is because IE does not support arrow functions.

Comment: @ArunKumarM And that was the reason to unaccept my answer? Note that **you didn't** mention anything about compatibility with IE. You could just tell me it instead of unaccepting my answer. This is just wrong and you have disappointed me.

Answer (score 3):

using Object.entries

```js
var arr = {
  "3/10/2017": 52,
  "3/11/2017": 58,
  "3/12/2017": 70,
  "3/13/2017": 76
};

arr = Object.entries(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: `Object.entries` method is unfortunately not supported by IE or Opera. At all.

Comment: Polyfills change that sad state of affairs